When an external Bluetooth keyboard is connected to a Pixel phone, how do you disable/enable the virtual keyboard?
When I have connected an external Bluetooth speaker to the mobile phone, I want to disable or enable the virtual keyboard that is visible on the mobile phone. How to do this?

Related, or half/possible dupe: How do I force the 'showing' of an onscreen keyboard (soft-keyboard) when already 'paired' with a bluetooth keyboard?
